# How to get top 10 items based on category in joined table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can get the top 1000 selling items from a sales table in a day (and display item info from another table) with the following query:

```
 select
    cs.item_no, sum(quantity) as quantity, i.item_type, i.item_name, i.group_name
    FROM `sales` cs
    left join 
    (
    SELECT 
                item_no,
                MIN(item_name) as item_name,
                MIN(item_type) as item_type,
                MIN(group_name) as group_name,
                
        FROM 
                `items` 
        WHERE group_name!='UNKNOWN'
        GROUP BY
                item_no 
    ) i
    on cs.item_no = i.item_no 
    where date BETWEEN '2022-08-21' AND '2022-08-22'
    group by item_no,  i.item_type, i.item_name, i.group_name
    order by sum(quantity) desc
    limit 1000
```

The query displays top 1000 items by quantity sold and also shows the item's type, name and group_name. How can I modify this query so that I can see the top 10 items for each group_name? So instead of top 1000 items overall, I want to see the top 10 items in each group_name.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does below SQL works ?
Basically i created a subquery to calculate rank over partition on item group and then ordered by quantity.
A filter on rank column will display top 10 records for each group.

```
select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name
FROM (
select subq.*, rank() over (partition by group_name order by group_name,quantity desc) as rn 
FROM ( select
    cs.item_no, sum(quantity) as quantity, i.item_type, i.item_name, i.group_name
    FROM `sales` cs
    left join 
    (
    SELECT 
                item_no,
                MIN(item_name) as item_name,
                MIN(item_type) as item_type,
                MIN(group_name) as group_name,
                
        FROM 
                `items` 
        WHERE group_name!='UNKNOWN'
        GROUP BY
                item_no 
    ) i
    on cs.item_no = i.item_no 
    where date BETWEEN '2022-08-21' AND '2022-08-22'
    group by item_no,  i.item_type, i.item_name, i.group_name) subq) outerqry
WHERE rn<=10
```

Comment: I had no idea about subqueries, thanks. If i want to add 'quantity' column to the final output, I just need to add it in the first select statement? So select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name, quantity

Comment: Quantity is already summed in inner query. If you want to sum again, do it in outermost select clause. And subquery is query inside query... `select empid from (select empid , name from emp where sal>100)`

Comment: In the first line, if I use `select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name, sum(quantity)` I get an error `SELECT list expression references column item_no which is neither grouped nor aggregated`. But when I use `select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name, quantity` it seems to work.

Comment: Which means you arent adding those columns in group by clause. Whole sql should look like `select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name, sum(quantity) from (above sql in answer) rs group by select item_no,item_type, item_name, group_name`. Also remove order by from above sql.

Comment: do you mean `rn` instead of `rs`? If possible could you edit the answer? I don't understand why I should use `sum(quantity)` again instead of just `quantity` in the first line.

Comment: Thats exactly what i asked before - `Quantity is already summed in inner query. `. so i dont htink youhave to sum again. So, the SQL should be good for you. Is the output not fitting with your expectations?